# Selenium to select and click on correct link

Tags: c#, selenium

Please dont get bored of answering my questions continuously for the same type of data. I am using Selenium and c# for my application. Here also I have a web page with contents like this:

```
Description     App Name    Information
 Some Desc1     App1         Some Info
 Some Desc2     App2         Some Info
 Some Desc3     App2         Some Info
 Some Desc4     App3         Some Info
 Some Desc5     App4         Some Info
```

As said in my earlier questions, in my application the user enters an appname of his own choice. And that appname I have stored it in a variable. What I need to do is that, I want selenium to search for that appname and it must click on corresponding Description of that.

An example scenario is: If the user enters APP2, then selenium should search for the appname "App2" and after that first it should click on Some Desc2 and then after some time it should click on some Desc3. For Your Information, all the "some Desc's" links have no classname, no id, and have same tagname.

Comment: Is your data displayed in a `<table>` element?

Comment: @MarkRowlands: Yes..You are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("table-id"));
List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
for (WebElement row : rows) {
    List<WebElemebt> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    if (cells[1].getText().equals("AppNameYouWantToFind")) {
        cells[0].click();
    }
}
```

I hope you understand what's going on here but I'll describe it anyway.

First, you find the `table` with the relevant data. Then you find each of the `rows` within that table, forming a list of webelemebts. For each of those rows you then create a list of all the `cells`. Due to your table layout you know that the `App Name` data is located in the second cell in your list, 'index=[1]'. So make a comparison there for the search term you want - if it matches click the proceeding `cell`.

That's in Java I'm afraid, you'll have to convert that to c#.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("table-id"));
List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); //get list to know how many times to loop
for (int i=0; i<rows.length(); i++) {
    rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); //this is required as you'll be 'refreshing' the list to avoid 'stale element exceptions' after going back
    List<WebElemebt> cells = rows[i].findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    if (cells[1].getText().equals("AppNameYouWantToFind")) {
        cells[0].click();
        //do what you need to do on the new page
        driver.navigate.back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Let me convert and try in my app. I got my table id as "{E165D2BB-A232-40D8-B848-9816FC299A4B}-{696D6B29-5A5D-47F3-97CF-ECBFDD1E2CE8}". Can it be my table id? Or Am I wrong?

Comment: Also, can I desfine rows, cells as variable? That means var rows and var cells??

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the List<type> declarations, sorry been a while since I've written java. As for the table-id, I meant the reference via the `html` of your webpage. If it's not got an `id` use `xpath` or similar.

Comment: Yes..I think your code is working. But it is not clicking anything as we say on the code. I think it is because I have so many items with the same appname. I want it like this: It should click on the first found item, then go back, then click on 2nd..like wise until it cant find any with the entered name..Can I have anything like that??

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "go back", as in clicking the browser back button perhaps?

Comment: Rownalds: I mean clicking on description link will take the browser into a newpage. So, to go to next description of same app, we need to move back. Hope you got an idea.

Comment: Sure, ok, that requires a little more work involving a `counter` type loop and referencing the index of the row. I'll edit with an updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your update on answer. I will try your code and will get back to you if something goes wrong..

Comment: Before I could try your code I need to achieve another requirement. Could you please have a look at this and comment your idea on that too??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094706/selenium-to-click-on-an-app-name-in-a-filter-tool