# selenium to click on several links one after other

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a table over a webpage having many values repeating like this:

```
Description     App Name    Information
Some Desc1       App1         Some Info
Some Desc2       App2         Some Info
Some Desc3       App2         Some Info
Some Desc4       App3         Some Info
Some Desc5       App4         Some Info
```

At the start of my app, it will ask the user to enter an appname of their choice. What I want is if I choose APP2 it should select "Some Desc2" first, that will lead to another page and there I will do something. Then again it should come back to previous page and this time it should select "Some Desc3", that will lead to another page. This should be repeated n number of times until selenium can't find an appname specified.

I have tried as shown below:

```
//Finding Table, its rows and coloumns
int rowcount = driver.FindElements(By.Id("someid")).Count;
for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
{
//Finding App name based on user entered text
  var elems = driver.FindElements(By.PartialLinkText(text));
  IList<IWebElement> list = elems;
  for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
  {
    var table = driver.FindElement(By.Id("someid"));
    IList<IWebElement> rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
    IList<IWebElement> cells = rows[i].FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
    //Again finding element based on user entered text
    var elem = driver.FindElements(By.PartialLinkText(text));
    list = elem;
    if (list[1].Text.Equals(text))
    {
      list[0].Click();
      string duration;
      string price;
      var elements = driver.FindElements(By.Id("SPFieldNumber"));
      IList<IWebElement> lists = elements;
      duration = lists.First().Text.ToString();
      price = lists.ElementAt(1).Text.ToString();
      MessageBox.Show(duration);
      MessageBox.Show(price);
      driver.Navigate().Back();
    }
 }
```

}

Running this code selects "Some Desc2" correctly and everything went fine. But after returning to the previous page c# throws an exception "element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up selenium".

Comment: At which line is this thrown?

Comment: @Arran: After if (list[1].Text.Equals(text)){

Comment: You're still stuck on this? My gosh... I showed you how to deal with the 'stale element exceptions' in the previous question you asked. You don't use a `for (WEbElemet element : elements)` style loop. You need to use a counter `for (i=0; i<elements.length(); i++)` style that immediately rebuilds the list each time and 'remembers' the next position by referencing the counter as the index.

Comment: @MarkRowlands: Actually I forgot. I changed like this.Instead of foreach loop I changed it as for (int j=0; j < list.Count; j++), but unfortunately throws the same exception.

Comment: Looking at what you have here and what you posted in your previous question - it looks like your doing the same thing twice and this is what is causing your issue.
You need to click on the associated `Desc` for the given `AppName`. As these are both within the same `row`, you create a list of `cells` but then you never use that list! Instead you create another list trying to find the elements that match the `appname text` - which will only ever be one element in each row.

Comment: @MarkRowlands: Instead you create another list trying to find the elements that match the appname text - which will only ever be one element in each row--sorry, I couldn't follow you. Could you please clarify it once again?

Comment: I can't make it any simpler, sorry.

Comment: @MarkRowlands: I tried your idea. But again it failed with the same exception. Instead of this approach, I could see another approach and tried that one with my knowledge. Could you please check my approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118691/selenium-to-read-the-corresponding-data-and-store-in-a-variable

Comment: @MarkRowlands: Please see my edited code above. That stale element exception now gone. The created list has got so many rows and columns with that one particular app name. But it clicks on the same link.That is in my example above,if it is app2, it keeps on clicking in "some desc2" rather than first "some desc 2" and then "some desc 3". Now what is the mistake which I am doing?

Answer (score 2):

For this particular issue, you find `table` and `row` elements before the loop, then by calling `driver.Navigate().Back();` inside the loop, your `table` and `row` are no longer in the DOM (because your page changes, DOM changes, the table element is not the one you find outside the loop anymore)

Try put them inside the loop

```
int rowCount = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#table_id tr")).Count; // replace table_id with the id of your table
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount ; i++)
{
    var table = driver.FindElement(By.Id("some ID"));
    rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
    // the rest of the code
}
```

However, apart from solving your problems, I really suggest you read the [Selenium documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html) and learn some basic C# programming first, this will save you a lot time asking questions here.

- Why are you doing this every time?

```cs
var elems = driver.FindElements(By.PartialLinkText(text));
IList<IWebElement> list = elems;

// IList<IWebElement> list = driver.FindElements(By.PartialLinkText(text));
```

- `element.Text` is the string type you want, no need for calling `ToString()`

```cs
lists.First().Text.ToString();
// lists.First().Text;
```

- You don't need this if there's no frames involved.

```cs
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

- (from your earlier post) A list of `IWebElement` would never equal to a string, and the result can't be an element. Avoid using `var` if you don't know what type you want, as it may get you a totally different thing.

```cs
IList<IWebElement> list = elems;
var elem= list.Equals(text);
```

- (from your earlier post) `element.ToString()` and `element.Text` are different

```cs
string targetele = elem.ToString(); // you want elem.Text;
```

Comment: Your code fragment int rowCount = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#table_id tr")); doesn't seems to be working. Error thrown is cannot implicitly convert type (IWebElement) to int.

Comment: @VysakhVenugopal: Error message tells you all. Here I made a mistake, it should be `int rowCount = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#table_id tr")).Count`;. Really simple compilation error, you should be able to figure out easily.

Comment: But then also, unfortunately it throws the same exception.

Comment: @VysakhVenugopal: Sounds like C# compilation error again, not about Selenium logic, you should be able to debug yourself. If you can't get it working, please post stacktrace.

Comment: Tried solving the issue.but unfortunately, couldn't. So, I have tried another approach for the same thing which I am trying to  do now. You may please look at it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118691/selenium-to-read-the-corresponding-data-and-store-in-a-variable

Comment: Please see my edited code above. That stale element exception now gone. The created list has got so many rows and columns with that one particular app name. But it clicks on the same link.That is in my example above,if it is app2, it keeps on clicking in "some desc2" rather than first "some desc 2" and then "some desc 3". Now what is the mistake which I am doing?

Comment: @VysakhVenugopal: Good to know. Would you care to accept answer if it's fixed. This one and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094706/selenium-to-click-on-an-app-name-in-a-filter-tool). http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: Actually I have not tried that one as this is not fixed yet. I will try and update it once it is okay. Don't worry..